# value of input changes div's content dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

im kinda new to javascript. I would like to multiple the total value by the days value dynamically. Was trying for some time but couldnt find the solution. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.kalorie').click(function() {

    var varKalorie = $('input[name=kalorie]:checked').val()
    $('.posilki').prop("disabled", false);

    if (varKalorie == 1000) {

      $('.posilki').click(function() {
        var total = 0;

        $('.posilki:checked').each(function() {
          var posilkiChecked = $('.posilki:checked').length;
          if (posilkiChecked >= 3) {
            posilkiEach = parseFloat($(this).val());
            total += posilkiEach;
            $('.qtyminus').prop("disabled", false);
            $('.qtyplus').prop("disabled", false);
          } else {
            total = "Musisz zaznaczyc przynajmniej 3 dania";
          }
        });

        $('#total').html(total);

      });
    }

    if (varKalorie == 1250) {

      $('.posilki').click(function() {
        var total = 0;

        $('.posilki:checked').each(function() {
          var posilkiChecked = $('.posilki:checked').length;
          if (posilkiChecked >= 3) {
            posilkiEach = parseFloat($(this).val()) * 1.1;
            total += posilkiEach;
            $('.qtyminus').prop("disabled", false);
            $('.qtyplus').prop("disabled", false);
          } else {
            total = "Musisz zaznaczyc przynajmniej 3 dania";
          }
        });

        $('#total').html(total + 'pln');

      });
    }

    if (varKalorie == 1500) {

      $('.posilki').click(function() {
        var total = 0;

        $('.posilki:checked').each(function() {
          var posilkiChecked = $('.posilki:checked').length;
          if (posilkiChecked >= 3) {
            posilkiEach = parseFloat($(this).val()) * 1.2;
            total += posilkiEach;
            $('.qtyminus').prop("disabled", false);
            $('.qtyplus').prop("disabled", false);
          } else {
            total = "Musisz zaznaczyc przynajmniej 3 dania";
          }
        });

        $('#total').html(total + 'pln');

      });
    }

    if (varKalorie == 2000) {

      $('.posilki').click(function() {
        var total = 0;

        $('.posilki:checked').each(function() {
          var posilkiChecked = $('.posilki:checked').length;
          if (posilkiChecked >= 3) {
            posilkiEach = parseFloat($(this).val()) * 1.4;
            total += posilkiEach;
            $('.qtyminus').prop("disabled", false);
            $('.qtyplus').prop("disabled", false);
          } else {
            total = "Musisz zaznaczyc przynajmniej 3 dania";
          }
        });

        $('#total').html(total + 'pln');

      });
    }

    if (varKalorie == 2500) {

      $('.posilki').click(function() {
        var total = 0;

        $('.posilki:checked').each(function() {
          var posilkiChecked = $('.posilki:checked').length;
          if (posilkiChecked >= 3) {
            posilkiEach = parseFloat($(this).val()) * 1.6;
            total += posilkiEach;
            $('.qtyminus').prop("disabled", false);
            $('.qtyplus').prop("disabled", false);
          } else {
            total = "Musisz zaznaczyc przynajmniej 3 dania";
          }
        });

        $('#total').html(total + 'pln');

      });
    }
  });

  console.log($('#total').text());

  // This button will increment the value
  $('.qtyplus').click(function(e) {
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
    // If is not undefined
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      // Increment
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
      // Otherwise put a 0 there
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
    }
  });
  // This button will decrement the value till 0
  $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
    // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
      // Decrement one
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
      // Otherwise put a 0 there
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
    }
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="global-title">Cennik</h2>
  <input type="radio" name="kalorie" class="kalorie" value="1000" />1000
  <input type="radio" name="kalorie" class="kalorie" value="1250" />1250
  <input type="radio" name="kalorie" class="kalorie" value="1500" />1500
  <input type="radio" name="kalorie" class="kalorie" value="2000" />2000
  <input type="radio" name="kalorie" class="kalorie" value="2500" />2500
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <input type="checkbox" class="posilki" value="15" disabled/>Śniadanie
  <input type="checkbox" class="posilki" value="10" disabled/>2 Śniadanie
  <input type="checkbox" class="posilki" value="20" disabled/>obiad
  <input type="checkbox" class="posilki" value="10" disabled/>podwieczorek
  <input type="checkbox" class="posilki" value="15" disabled/>kolacja
  <br/>Days

  <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' disabled/>
  <input type='text' name='quantity' value='30' class='qty' id="days-input" disabled/>
  <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' disabled/>

  <br/>
  <br/>Total:
  <div id="total">0 zł</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include a minimal example with relevant code to your problem, also include relevant code in the question. It seems like you are asking for a simple task, if so there isn't a need to have a complex example. Also I would encourage you to have examples in English, as I have no idea what your fiddle is doing.

Comment: Sorry. I made changes to jsfiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/7ejvvk86/8/
The main task is that u choose calories then choose some of the meals (each of them has special price) And it calculates the price. Then it should multiple by number of days changed by plus or minus. Hope that explains. Thanks for response.

Comment: zl, that's Polish Zloty, right?  ... Anyway, I don't exactly understand what the calories have to do with the equation.  You seem to not use that result in any meaningful way (well, yes, I see some factor changing: 1, 1.2, 1.4, ...in your first jsFiffle).  You should use that value in the function that calculates the end result, I guess.  Can you give the basic mathematical equation of your app?

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay Look here  jsfiddle.net/7ejvvk86/8 
I removed all not necesarry part of code. In my app user should be able to choose one of the few amount of calories (1000, 1250 ...) Then able to choose meals(at least 3, each of them has price - 15, 10, 20..) 1000 is start, every 250 calories more - every meal is 10% more expensive. At the end is for how much days u want to order. If its more then 30days it should be 20% discount for whole price. How it explains. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention are kind of new to javascript ... my main message is to put things in functions.

This obliges you to think: "okay, what exactly do I need to know to perform this?" ... well those are the parameters of your function.

Ad of course, functions dramatically reduces code, you don't have to copy/paste everything 6 times.

Notice: you could put all the functions within document.ready, if you want.

And, oh yes, I added label elements.  This makes it nicer to the client.

Is this it?

```
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="global-title">Cennik</h2>

  <input type="radio" name="kalorie" class="kalorie" value="1000" id="r0" /><label for="r0">1000</label>
  <input type="radio" name="kalorie" class="kalorie" value="1250" id="r1" /><label for="r1">1250</label>
  <input type="radio" name="kalorie" class="kalorie" value="1500" id="r2" /><label for="r2">1500</label>
  <input type="radio" name="kalorie" class="kalorie" value="2000" id="r3" /><label for="r3">2000</label>
  <input type="radio" name="kalorie" class="kalorie" value="2500" id="r4" /><label for="r4">2500</label>
  <br/><br/>

  <input type="checkbox" class="posilki" id="sniadanie" value="15" ><label for="sniadanie">Sniadanie</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="posilki" id="sniadanie2" value="10" ><label for="sniadanie2">2 Sniadanie</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="posilki" id="obiad" value="20" ><label for="obiad">obiad</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="posilki" id="podwieczorek" value="10" ><label for="podwieczorek">podwieczorek</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="posilki" id="kolacja" value="15" ><label for="kolacja">kolacja</label>
  <br/><br/>Days

  <input type="button" value="-" class="qtyminus" field="quantity" >
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="30" class="qty" id="days-input" >
  <input type="button" value="+" class="qtyplus" field="quantity" >

  <br/>
  <br/>Total:
  <div id="total">0 zl</div>
</div>
<style>
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

// calculates the total price, displays it in id="total"
function calculateTotal(sum_price, days) {
  var result = sum_price * days;
  $('#total').html(result + ' zl');
  return result; // not really being used
}

// reads the checked checkboxes, returns their sum value
function readSumPrice() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.posilki').each(function(i) {
    if(this.checked) {
      sum += Number($(this).val());
    }
  });
  return sum;  
}

// what ever the client changes, triggers this function.  We don't really care what has just been clicked on, we have to recalculate it anyway.
function somethingChanged() {
  // first we want to check if three meals have been chosen
  var numberOfMealsChosen = $( ".posilki:checked" ).length;
  if(numberOfMealsChosen >= 3) {
    // now we calculate
    var sum_price = readSumPrice();
    var days = Number($('#days-input').val());
    calculateTotal(sum_price, days);
  }
  else {
    $('#total').html('please choose 3 items');
  }
}

// now the events
$(document).ready(function() {
  // click on +
  $('.qtyplus').click(function() {
    var days = Number($('#days-input').val());
    $('#days-input').val(days + 1);
    somethingChanged();
  });

  // click on -
  $('.qtyminus').click(function() {
    var days = Number($('#days-input').val());
    // let's put 0 as minimum
    if(days > 0) {
      $('#days-input').val(days - 1);
      somethingChanged();
    }
  });

  // click on checkbox
  $('.posilki').click(function() {
    somethingChanged();
  });

  // click on radio.  triggers the calculation but doesn't really affect anything (yet?)
  $('.kalorie').click(function() {
    somethingChanged();
  });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I wanted. Thanks for response and whats most important to me explanation/comments. Really appreciatve it.

Comment: Okay, Glad to help.